# Adding a contact form to my Joomla site

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I have a Joomla site, on which site you can exchange ebooks. This is the feature I want to add, but don't know how:

---

When someone is interested in an ebook, he can click on a "REQUEST EBOOK" button.

The "request button" will forward an e-mail to the registered user and owner of ebook with a specific message.

---

Basically I need a script that does this:

"If I click on the "REQEUST EBOOK" button, take the email address of the ebook owner and registered user, compose a predefined message,and send it to him/her.

QUESTION: how could I achieve a similar result? Please keep in mind that I don't know anything about PHP.

Thanks a MILLION.

dimitri

PS: to get a better idea, visit http://www.ebook123.it. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a contact form. Does Joomla have a plugins library that you could choose and install from?

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that you'll need to be willing to do the necessary installation and/or programming. If you don't know *anything* about PHP it might be worth getting some local help :)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has lots of useful plugins/extensions etc, have a look at these contact forms and see which one you like the look of:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms

Some are very simple to use, others a bit more complicated.